# CodeIgniter Change URL Routes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Real Estate Site, in CodeIgniter my link names is:

`htp://examplesite(dot)com/property/31/en/property_title`

I want to replace it with:

`htp://examplesite(dot)com/my-custom-slug.htm`

or

`htp://examplesite(dot)com/property_title`

Both ways might be ok. My routes are:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "frontend";
$route['404_override'] = 'frontend';

/* Custom routing */
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard';
//$route['secret'] = 'admin/dashboard';

// To change property->listing in uri
$route['listing/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "property/$1/$2/$3";
$route['listing/(:num)/(:any)'] = "property/$1/$2";
```

what is the best way in this case?

I know there is a possible solution that:

Add

$config['listing_uri'] = 'listing';

Than add to:

In ‘application\config\routes.php’

After:

```
$route['listing/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "property/$1/$2/$3";
$route['listing/(:num)/(:any)'] = "property/$1/$2";
```

Add also:

```
$route['changed/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "property/$1/$2/$3";
$route['changed/(:num)/(:any)'] = "property/$1/$2";
```

but is there any way to remove the 'listing', to see only the clean url (for better seo purpose) ??

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, luckily your problem isn't too big :)

Maybe have one slug before the property title to make the solution a bit more scalable:

```
$route["listing/(:any)"] = "property/view/$1";
```

Then point your browser to `yoursite.com/listing/some_slug` or `yoursite.com/listing/12`

You will need to have a slug associated with each property, otherwise you can use the id, and in the view function just retrieve the property based on the slug or id parameter.

If you don't want to include the `listing/` you might have problems down the line when trying to create other routes.

Comment: i just wrote the same thing but then you posted before me :-)

Comment: I know there is a solution to add: $config['listing_uri'] = 'listing'; than add $route['changed/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "property/$1/$2/$3";
$route['changed/(:num)/(:any)'] = "property/$1/$2"; but i want to remove the listing, and to see only examplesite(dot)com/custom_slug.htm is there any way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with the above, can you please elaborate? You can use the above mentioned solution without the listing part, and if you have any other specific routes just add it before this route in the config file, as codeigniter interprets it top to bottom. The problem with this is you are assuming anything after your domain name is a valid listing, so your validation would just need to be sound, and show 404 if the listing doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry....... So basically my problem is when created a new property, i need htp://examplesite(dot)com/my-custom-slug.htm but now i have htp://examplesite(dot)com/property/31/en/property_title (the last one, its hard to SEO)

Comment: My above mentioned answer should do the trick, just remove the listing/, as long as your properties have slugs, if you want to set a file extension, have a look in the config.php file, I'm not at a pc now, but there's a config item to set the extension of your routes to pretty much anything, so you could tell codeigniter to add the .htm

Comment: if i completely remove the listing/ and add the htm in the config.php maybe its a working solution?

Comment: Sound like it, just remember to define the other routes your website uses before this one, otherwise things like contact etc will get caught by your route which handle the listings